# Prevent from exposing jSON data - wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/

Tags: json, wordpress, contact-form-7

Can anyone help us, how to prevent exposing jSON values in WP Contact Form 7? I have copied a screen shot for reference. It impacts form validations if we stop the service via WordPress plugin - Disable Rest API.

Also, I would like to know what are the major security issues by using this plugin along with below service URL.

[image: Screen shot of the json format]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I do not see any vulnerabilities here. These are default paths and do not expose any login, username, password, private directory, paths or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it via Disable Rest API plugin. I have enabled only the option - /contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/(?P\d+)/feedback

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the folder you need to "lock"  create .htaccess file with the following content:

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using IIS and I have created a web config file with following script and copied into 'wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7' but still no luck. 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator"/>
            <deny users="*" />              
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>